# Is there a way to simulate the drag effect created by acceleration while in a stationary object?

Tags: experimental-physics, acceleration, drag

There was a video of a train that had tvs in the windows so it appeared the rider was moving across the landscape. If the train was stationary the passenger would not believe the ride was real because they would not feel the drag from acceleration. See racing arcade games.

Is there any way to simulate the acceleration effect? As if you were in a race car going from 0 to 60?

I think about this a lot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl9u5.jpg

Comment: If the train is stationary, then drag due to train velocity will be zero. Wind induced drag may not be though.

Comment: Try one of those VR simulators, Canyon Run etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*the drag from acceleration*"

This isn't called drag. It's just called force or perhaps inertia.

No you can't, not completely stationary anyways. The body detects forces based on deformations relative to various parts of itself. The sensation of acceleration is due to the deformation produced by inertia of all parts of the body, including internal organs.

So you need a way to apply force to internal organs as well; just external pressure is not enough. This is why leaning your back against the wall feels different than being pushed back into your seat when a car accelerates forward.

And even leaning against a wall can't be reproduced artificially because that is using gravity and the way gravity can pull on all parts of your body equally means you don't feel pressure on your front like when someone is pushing your back against a wall.

The only thing I know that can reach inside the body to do that is gravity so artificial gravity or some other form of full-body acceleration.

The closest thing right now would probably be a room built inside a centrifuge. Like those flying saucer rides spin and stick you to the walls at a carnival due to the centripetal force.

Or that NASA G-force pilot machine that spins your chair in a circle.

Comment: But see kamran's explanation of visual cues.  That's why some people get "airsick" when watching  OmniTheatre or other surround-image video.

Answer (score 3):

The rides in Disneyland do a great job of combing the visual cues of the ride with actually accelerating the vehicle or boat or rocket but in a carefully designed short span giving the impression of larger acceleration during a longer time.

The displacement follows a pattern of fast short acceleration amplified with the visuals. then a gentle recoil while visual cues give the impression of coasting.